# Tag Synonym Request

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I'm so far away from even suggesting synonyms that I'm going to buck convention and start here...

Can someone please make [elder-dragon-highlander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-dragon-highlander) and [edh](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edh) synonyms of [commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commander)?

Commander is the modern name and was probably adopted to avoid copyright issues with the Highlander movies (since both are focused on the tag "There can only be one")

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms for those with enough rep to create/vote on tag synonyms.

At this point it looks like we're only talking about a few questions, so I'm not sure that a global synonym is required.  Can this be handled by just retagging the affected questions?

Comment: Don't have enough rep or I'd have already been there :-)  We are looking at a few questions but I think both terms are so ubiquitous  that retagging means committing to a lifetime of retagging.  Additionally most Magic the Gathering questions generally only carry 1 tag ... the MTG tag.  As the topic expands I'm certain we'll see more use.

Comment: While we're at it, just for brevity and convenience perhaps an [mtg] tag could be created as a nice synonym for [magic-the-gathering]?

Answer (score 1):

I'm moving the [commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commander) to [mtg-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander).

We should avoid using generic terms as tags when we only want to represent a subset of a particular game.